# Sveltekit unable to read data from POST formdata

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Just trying the below in Sveltekit (3.44) but the console always outputs:

```
Got data FormData {}
```

The request is simply (made via Postman):

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:3000/todos.json \
  --header 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001' \
  --form test=hello
```

Code:
**src/routes/todos/index.json.ts**

```
export const post: RequestHandler = async (request) => {
    const data = await request.request.formData();
    console.log('Got data', data);
    return {
        status: 200,
        body: 'text'
    }
}
```

Othen than destructuring and cleaning up this code - why is formData empty ?

NB When setting the data line to await request.request.text() I receive (which shows I am receiving data):

```
Got data --X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="test"

hello
--X-INSOMNIA-BOUNDARY--
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known one : https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/4198 This isn't a bug, it's just hard to log the form data, and make use of it. As suggested in the link, use the following if you really wish to log it in the console:

```
const body = await event.request.formData();

// to get everything
console.log(...body); // ["name", "Rich Harris"] ["hobbies", "svelte"], ["hobbies", "journalism"]

// if you know you don't have duplicates
console.log(Object.fromEntries(body)); // { name: "Rich Harris", hobbies: "journalism" }
```

I haven't had any problem using 'await request.json()', except for when I had to implement file uploads to the API. It gives me a huge headache, and I always end up using the S3 bucket, or make a special API for this with Python, or Express.js.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - shame the resulting code has a typescript error of:       Type 'FormData' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.ts(2488)        for the spread operator and         the Object.fromEntries shows a different TS error - Not to be discussed here though :) Thanks for the detailed response